# "_bidirectional_stream_destroy", referenced from:

Tags: ios, grpc, quic, http3, cronet

i'm trying to use grpc+quic on iOS.
the podspec is

```
  pod 'gRPC-ProtoRPC'
  pod 'gRPC-Core/Cronet-Implementation'
  pod 'gRPC/GRPCCoreCronet'
```

then buildsuccss but link error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_bidirectional_stream_destroy", referenced from:
      on_succeeded(bidirectional_stream*) in cronet_transport.o
      on_failed(bidirectional_stream*, int) in cronet_transport.o
      on_canceled(bidirectional_stream*) in cronet_transport.o
  "_bidirectional_stream_create", referenced from:
      execute_stream_op(op_and_state*) in cronet_transport.o
  "_bidirectional_stream_delay_request_headers_until_flush", referenced from:
      execute_stream_op(op_and_state*) in cronet_transport.o
```

any one knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

the CornetFramewrok.framewrok imported by cocoapods is just have i386,x86_64

i download the Cornet.framework and Manuel rename to  CornetFramewrok and imported with local path. solve this proble